# Can [:1] be used in place of [0]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, slice

I was reading the source code of the Python xml.etree.ElementTree module (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py) and I came across an interesting use of slices. The authors wrote the following code:

```
prefix = text[:1]
```

Which as far as I can tell is identical to:

```
try:
    prefix = text[0]
except IndexError:
    prefix = text
```

Are these code snippets identical? What are the benefits and detriments of using [:1] in place of [0]?

Comment: They're identical for strings, not necessarily for other sequence types.  For example, in the case of lists, `[:1]` is always a list (of length 0 or 1), `[0]` is a list element which may be of any type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other difference: `text[0]` results in an exception if `text` is an empty list, while `text[:1]` returns an empty list. Similarly, indexing an empty string will give you an exception while slicing returns an empty string.

Comment: I've noticed the difference between text[0] and text[:1] when text is empty. To me it seems that text[:1] is a way to silently avoid raising IndexErrors. Is it a better practice to enclose "text[0]" in a try/except block than to use "text[:1]"?

Comment: I don't think one is better practice than the other. It all depends on what your're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in the output format:

`a[:1]` returns a list with the first element. While `a[0]` returns the first element.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a[:1]
[1]
>>> a[0]
1
```

Comment: While this may be true for slicing lists, the source code in reference is using slices on strings. Both text[0] and text[:1] return a string.

Answer (score 0):

Slices -- [:1] -- return a list, whereas [0] returns an atom.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is scoped by string usage only, then yes – they are identical. You get benefit from less code, but second snippet is more pythonic and explicit.